# How do programs like man, screen, and vim create temporary overlays?

Tags: shell, terminal, tput

Several *NIX commands, such as `screen`, `man`, `vim` and others, create a temporary canvas/screen/overlay in a shell environment. When such programs execute, they cover or hide whatever content was displayed in the terminal before — almost like a "full screen" mode, within the terminal window. When they terminate, however, they reveal or restore whatever had been on the terminal before.

In the example below, I create some filler text on the screen, then invoke `man bash`. The man page opens up and covers all other characters on the terminal display. When I close the man page, the characters that had been covered up are again shown.

## Before

[image: terminal screen capture before running <code>man bash</code>]

## While an example full-screen program is running

[image: Screencap of the man page for Bash]

## After

[image: Screencap of the terminal after running <code>man bash</code>]

I would expect that programs writing to stdout/stderr could accomplish the first step (replacing the content of the terminal with program-specific content), but then it would produce a ton of text that I could scroll through, and therefore couldn't do the second step: *restoring* the contents of the terminal. That means that somehow either the program memorizes the previous contents of the screen and re-outputs them (I doubt it?), or it creates some sort of sub-window within a terminal and something else keeps track of the previous contents of the terminal.

## My Question

**How can I accomplish that behavior in my own program and/or script?**

Perhaps I should use curses/ncurses, tput, termcap/terminfo, or ANSI escape sequences?

## Update:

This revised question is essentially the same as https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27941/show-output-on-another-screen-and-return-to-normal-when-done. (I hadn't found it when I had written this question despite lots of searching.) The difference is that my question is more general (any language) whereas that question is specific to Bash. The answers to both questions are essentially the same. If it's too similar to a question on another site, feel free to close it here for *that* reason.

Comment: @Rob — They are all terminal applications. There's no window manager involved.

Comment: @Quentin it looks like a Mac. I'm betting his terminal is running on that desktop

Comment: @Quentin is correct. This behavior is the same regardless of OS (macOS, Linux), terminal (Terminal.app, iTerm2.app, Putty, Konsole, xTerm, others), or even shell (bash, zsh, csh, tcsh, ksh, and even a toy shell I wrote).

Comment: The source for Man is here.  Feel free to just go see what it does:
https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/man-db.git

Comment: @Rob — Probably has something to do with your terminal or its configuration; not the windowing environment or lack thereof.

Comment: Go into your favorite terminal. Use TERM=xterm-256color see overlay.  Change to vt100, no overlay....

Comment: @Rob — https://imgur.com/TzyO5bA — There. That's a terminal on a linux VM with no X environment running.

Comment: Perhaps this discussion should be moved into a chat (I lack privileges to do so).

Comment: @user2199860: I don't know the details of that (though I could look it up soon), but setting the `TERM` environment variable definitely enables/disables the behavior I'm describing. That supports the conclusion @Quentin and @Rob are arriving at: that it's dependent on settings.

Comment: @Quentin That is not what I took as an overlay. I thought he was meaning another window on top.

Comment: @Rob Sorry for the confusion! Is it more clear now? (Feel free to edit my question text if you'd like to clarify it.)

Comment: @jvriesem It didn't help that I was reading and doing all this on a phone.

Comment: I'm curious why there were a bunch of downvotes and votes to close. It says it needs to be more focused, but it asks a limited, well-defined question: "how do programs do X?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How do these programs accomplish that behavior?

ANSI escape sequences. Try running this script:

```
#/bin/bash -
tput smcup
echo 'Hello world!'
sleep 3
tput rmcup
```

Using `infocmp`, you can see underlying sequences that create this overlaying effect, e.g:

```
$ infocmp -1 | grep 'rmcup\|smcup'
        rmcup=\E[?1049l\E[23;0;0t,
        smcup=\E[?1049h\E[22;0;0t,
```

> is this behavior shell-dependent or system-dependent?

None, it depends on whether the terminal emulator supports save/restore operations.